# MLB 2020 ?? postponed due to the COVID-19 pandemic

Tags: word-usage

[From wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Major_League_Baseball_season)

> The 2020 Major League Baseball season was originally scheduled to begin on March 26. However, the COVID-19 pandemic in North America caused Major League Baseball (MLB) to announce on March 12 that the remainder of spring training games were canceled and that the start of the regular season would be delayed by at least two weeks.

To describe the state of postponed, since then and is still in that state, should I say

> The 2020 Major League Baseball season has been postponed since then.

or

> The 2020 Major League Baseball season has been being postponed since then.

Are there any other options more natural and clear could be used here?

Comment: The usual expression is _has been postponed until [date]_ or, if no date has been set, _has been postponed indefinitely_. We can't say _has been being_ - the postponement was a decision taken in the past (in this case on March 12).

Comment: The Present Perfect Continuous passive (have/has been + Verb+ING) is rare in writing and rarer in speech, so use the Present Perfect  passive (has been + Past Participle), it's nearly always preferable.